# Memory allocation for 'Ref' and 'Out' parameter, any difference?

Tags: c#, ref, out

In C#, `ref` and `out` keyword.

How to it affect memory management? Is there any difference in memory management for `ref` and `out` keyword?

Answer (score 8):

Even though the mechanism used behind the scene is the same, the difference between the two keywords is in what the compiler must verify about each parameter:

- If you pass a parameter with `ref` keyword, the compiler checks that you have initialized it *before* making the call
- If you pass a parameter with `out` keyword, the compiler checks that the method that you call has made an assignment to the corresponding argument before exiting.

This difference allows for the [`out var` construct, which has been added to C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/). This feature would not be possible with `ref` alone because of the initialization requirement.

There is no difference between the two as far as the memory management is concerned: in both cases the reference itself is passed by value, and the code using the reference is adding an extra level of dereference.

Comment: How do memory management happen in case of "ref" and "Out" keyword? Is there any difference?

Comment: Nothing special is happening as far as the memory management is concerned: the reference is passed by value, and the code uses an additional level of dereference to get or set the actual value.